# Difference between || and ?? operators

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `??` and `||` in JS

```js
const a = {}

const b = a.name ?? 'varun 1'

console.log(b)

const d = a.name || 'varun 2'

console.log(d)
```

In the above code they both work the same. I know `||` is OR i.e if the first statement is `false` then set the value for the next one. Is it same for `??`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: Try it with `const a = {name: 0}`

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The main difference is that `nullish coalescing(??)` operator will only give the result as the right operand only if the left operand is either `null` or `undefined`.

Whereas the `OR(||)` operator will give the result as right operand for all the falsy values of the left operand.

Below are some examples

- Snippet 1: With `0` as input

```js
const a = 0;
// a || 10 --> Will result in 10, as || operator considers 0 as falsy value and resulting the right side operand
console.log(`a || 10 = ${a || 10}`);
// a ?? 10 --> Will result in 0, as ?? operator considers 0 as truthy value and resulting the left side operand
console.log(`a ?? 10 = ${a ?? 10}`);
```

- Snippet 2: With `''` as input

```js
const a = ''
console.log(`a || "ABC" = ${a || "ABC"}`); // ABC
console.log(`a ?? "ABC" = ${a ?? "ABC"}`); // ''
```

- Snippet 3: With `null` as input

```js
const a = null;
console.log(`a || 10 = ${a || 10}`); // 10
console.log(`a ?? 10 = ${a ?? 10}`); // 10
```

- Snippet 4: With `undefined` as input

```js
const a = {}
// Here a.name will be undefined, hence both of the operands results the right side operand
console.log(`a.name ?? 'varun 1' = ${a.name ?? 'varun 1'}`); // 'varun 1'
console.log(`a.name || 'varun 2' = ${a.name || 'varun 2'}`); // 'varun 2'
```

```js
const a = {name: ''}
// Here a.name will be '', then

// ?? will result ''
console.log(`a.name ?? 'varun 1' = ${a.name ?? 'varun 1'}`);
// || will result in 'varun 2'
console.log(`a.name || 'varun 2' = ${a.name || 'varun 2'}`);
```

- Snippet 5: With `false` as input

```js
const a = false;
console.log(`a || 10 = ${a || 10}`); // 10
console.log(`a ?? 10 = ${a ?? 10}`); // false
```

As mentioned above, both the operators behave similarly when the input is either `null` or `undefined`. The real difference we'll get to see when we provide `falsy` values such as `0`, `''`, `false`, `NaN`.

Comment: The main difference between ?? and || is how they handle falsy values. ?? only considers null and undefined as nullish, while || considers any falsy value as potentially false.

In summary, use the nullish coalescing operator ?? when you specifically want to handle null or undefined and use the logical OR operator || when you want to handle any falsy value (including null and undefined).

Answer (score 6):

You can see a difference in

```js
const a = ''

const b = a ?? 'varun 1'

console.log(b)

const d = a || 'varun 2'

console.log(d)
```

because `a ?? 'varun 1'` returns `'varun 1'` only if `a` is null or undefined but `a || 'varun 2'` returns `'varun 2'` if `a` is falsy. Some falsy values are empty strings, zero and boolean false.